# Cannot connect to Postgres via Sequel

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel, padrino

I am trying to use Padrino with Sequel and Postgres and am having no luck connecting.

In my pg_hba.conf I set the postgres user to 'trust' so no password is required (and can log in using PgAdmin without a password).

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
  local all             postgres                                trust
```

My Padrino connection looks like this:

```
Sequel::Model.plugin(:schema)
Sequel::Model.raise_on_save_failure = false # Do not throw exceptions on failure
Sequel::Model.db = case Padrino.env
  when :development then Sequel.connect(:adapter=>'postgres', :host=>'localhost', :database=>'padrino_template_development', :user=>'postgres', :password=>'', :loggers => [logger])
  when :production  then Sequel.connect("postgres://localhost/padrino_template_production",  :loggers => [logger])
  when :test        then Sequel.connect("postgres://localhost/padrino_template_test",        :loggers => [logger])
end
```

When I then try and run the rake task `sq:create`

I get this message

```
rake sq:create
=> Creating database 'padrino_template_development'
Password: 
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
<= sq:create executed
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2):

OK found the answer here, the problem is that the version of PgAdmin3 I was using had a bug in that made the user invalid as of 1970 when I changed the password.

The solution can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36137/postgresql-user-can-not-connect-to-server-after-changing-password/36181#36181)